# What does さばき切れます mean?

Tags: meaning, definitions

I ran across the sentence, さばき切れます, and I can't figure out what it means. Can anyone please explain? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the full sentence? The full sentence and some context would be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately that's all I have, and yest that's the full sentence.

Comment: When you say "that's all I have," do you mean there's no context whatsoever? And if so, how did you "run across" this word, and why do you care what it means?

Comment: It means that I read it in passing and I couldn't figure out what it means. I care because it caught my attention and haven't been able to find a definition in any dictionary or other source.

Comment: Do you still have access to the source where you read it in passing, and if so can you go back to it and fill in the context a little? If not, can you at least remember something about the context? Users of this site are very generous with their time and expertise, but they may not be able to help you if you aren't able to provide more information about how this word was used.

Comment: All I can remember is that this is a conversation about a contest, unfortunately. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, in your previous questions you have shown your effort to provide enough context, so I believe you, but you could have explained why the context was lacking. さばく has multiple meanings, and it's challenging to guess the intended meaning if there is absolutely no context.

Comment: Sure. I should have been more explicit about the lack of context

Answer (score 2):

さばき切る = さばく + し切る

- さばく = handle/dispose
- しきる = finish doing

...をさばききる ≒ I can manage ... or do it in time.

For example,
この魚さばき切れる？ = Can you dress this fish?

捌く is originally 'do something by hand' and 捌ける is a potential verb for it.
See also, はける

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense

Comment: Could you explain why there is a し in し切る? It doesn't feature in the compound さばき切る and I'm struggling to understand why it is しきる rather than just きる.

Comment: @user3856370, it's the same conjunction as the suffix added to the word 'access + able = accessible'.  走る+できる = 走れる or 歩く+できる= 歩ける　euphonic change, 'de + les = des'. These happen at a time.